# When should this question be answered?

Tags: mathematics, computer-puzzle, number-property

If you hover your mouse over the time marked in the right-bottom corner of this post, then you will see a string showing the exact time that I post this question, which reads `2021-03-18 22:32:47Z`. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119627/how-do-i-tell-exactly-what-time-an-answer-was-posted) for more details on how to check the exact time of posting.

Ignoring all non-digit characters, that time gives the number $20210318223247$. It turns out that this number has exactly $4$ divisors.

Now I offer a bounty of 500 reputations to reward any answer to this question whose posting time gives a number that has exactly $5$ divisors.

When should you post your answer?

<sub>Note: If you post a correct answer at a time that does not meet the above criterion, the answer will still be accepted. You just don't get the bounty.</sub>

Comment: FYI: At least on my browser - Chrome on a desktop, the time appears in the top-left, not the bottom-right.  Is it different for the mobile version?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: It's in both places, you can see it above the username in the bottom-right of the question too. Hover the "asked 16 hours ago" label (of whatever it may say at time of reading this).

Comment: Whoa, what? You can *view* the timestamp? I've been on Stack Exchange for over 8 years and this is the first time I've heard of this feature, lol I feel dumb...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm a very impatient person so I've decided not to wait around to post an answer at the right time which I think will be

> 7461-02-24 07:38:41Z

Reasoning

> Numbers which have exactly five divisors are those of the form $p^4$ where $p$ is a prime so it is a matter of searching through fourth powers of primes which look like a date and time (some get quite close).

Comment: Good job! Don't forget to come back for the bounty when it's the right time ^_^

Comment: No one wants to wait around for 918 years just for 500 rep points. So I am writing a script to do it...

Answer (score 13):

Having 5 divisors means

> that the number is exactly the fourth power of a prime number.

A standard number-theoretical way to observe this is

> to look at the properties of [Number of Divisors function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html) $\sigma_0(n)$, specifically $$ \sigma_0(p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots) = (1+e_1)(1+e_2)\cdots $$ Since this value is composite when $n$ has at least two distinct prime factors, and 5 is prime, the only way to satisfy the right side being 5 is that $n$ has a single prime factor $p_1$ and $e_1=4$, i.e. $n = p^4$.

So what we need to do now is

> write a program that goes through all primes after $^4\sqrt {20210318223247}$ and find the first one whose fourth power is a valid timestamp (has valid month, day, hour, minute, second).

Here is the code in **[Factor](https://factorcode.org/)**:

> ```
> 20210318223247 0.25 ^ 1 /i [ dup 4 ^
>   { [ 10 8 ^ / floor 100 mod 1 12 between? ]
>     [ 10 6 ^ / floor 100 mod 1 31 between? ]
>     [ 10000 / floor 100 mod 24 < ]
>     [ 100 / floor 100 mod 60 < ]
>     [ 100 mod 60 < ] } 1&&
> ] [ next-prime ] do until dup . 4 ^ .
> ```
>
> [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdCxasMwEAbgPU/xT9miSLKbhLTQsXTpUjqVBBxZJqK2zshn2hD67O7VHlqSaBD67z4OTlXhmNLw9vr88rTFh0/R12gKPo6XqvroOFDspkip9Gl6tik0voOj5hBiITM61R0p8cKF5PrAaJNnPgmLjPvBamt0ZjbWZjZfQyt7hz0MlgHvKPsWOfYz4CzJaGykt0RVEyWJGg2VYo3FwfOn9/ERO8GY8OomzswtLOfK2hwP/8kVWOkL8FfEN8x8PttJI/ovXoy/IuWS0EcO9bia@l0Oahh@AA)
>
> This code does not *very* rigorously check the validity of a timestamp, in that something like Feb 31 is not filtered out. Luckily, the first answer found has a well-formed month-day combination.

The output is

> $2939^4 = 74610224073841$, which maps to `7461-02-24 07:38:41Z`. It's way too distant in the future for us to wait for that time, as hexomino already pointed out :)

Comment: Ah ... very well-written answer! However you are just a tiiiiny bit slower than hexomino. I hope you understand that I give the green check to hexomino. Of course you still get my upvote!

Answer (score 2):

You need to post your answer on:

> A time that is the fourth power of a prime number. The other answers have already posted the first one that works.

The way to find this is:

> First, notice that it is somewhat difficult to have a number $n$ with an odd number of divisors. If $j$ is a divisor of $n$, then $\frac{n}{j} = k$ is also a divisor. The only way for divisors to not come in pairs is if you have a square number so that $j=k$. Thus our desired $n$ must be equal to the square of some number $m$. $m$ cannot be prime, otherwise $n$ would only have 3 factors. So $m$ has a factor $j$, meaning that $j$ and $mj$ are also factors of $n$. Thus the factors of $n$ are 1, $j$, $m$, $mj$, and $n$, so $j$ must be a prime number and $n=j^4$.

To make it even harder:

> Most primes still won't work. For example, $2129^4=20544834434881$, but unless there are some *significant* changes in the next 30 years there will not be a 34th day of the 48th month in 2054.

Comment: Notice that there is a `computer-puzzle` tag, which means that it is intended to be solved using a computer.

Comment: @WhatsUp I was writing up my explanation of why the number need to have the property that it does when Hexomino answered. I decided not to bother finishing my program to find it because I was already beaten to the punch.

Comment: Oh yes, I appreciate your detailed explanation (+1).